# Verify that shape character does not appear in specified Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where oval objects are added via a command button. Each time the command button is pressed, an oval is added with a character assigned. The first oval is assigned character "1", the second "2", third "3", and so on.

Sometimes an oval is deleted by accident. Once this happens, that character is lost. For example, say the command button has been pressed 5 times. There are now 5 ovals with 1-5 in each of them. If oval "2" is deleted, the command button can't recognize that this number has been deleted, and thus once pressed again, adds oval "6" instead of re-adding oval "2"

I have a cell range that adds information for each oval that is added. For example, once oval 1 is added, row 1 is filled with various info, including the character inside of that oval. Row 2 gets filled in with oval 2 info, and so on.

Even though oval "2" gets deleted, its info is retained in the table (on purpose). I tried creating loops that cross reference the table range and the characters in each existing oval shape so that if a row value doesn't have a shape, the system knows that it has to add that missing character oval first.

```
Sub VerifyTable()
Dim WeldNoRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WeldNoRange = ws.Range("A6:A76")
'If numbered oval shape doesn't exist, re-add that shape
For Each Cell In WeldNoRange
    If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
                If CInt(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text) = Cell.Value Then
                    Exit Sub 'Meaning that this weld no. does in fact have a weld indication
                Else
                    customweld = True
                        UserForm6_Help.Tag = "null"
                    n = CInt(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The problem with my solution is that it isn't explicit enough. Say oval "2" is missing... Once Cell.Value = "4", it checks all shapes in order from 1-4. Once it sees that oval "1" has the character "1" assigned, it interprets that CInt(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text) <> Cell.Value, meaning it thinks that oval "4" doesn't exist when it actually does.

What are my options to resolving this issue?

---->Edited so I can show what was implemented...

```
Sub AddMissingShape()
Dim WeldNoRange As Range, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim shp As Shape, s As Shape, b As Boolean

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WeldNoRange = ws.Range("A6:A76")

For Each Cell In WeldNoRange
    If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then
            For Each shp In ws.Shapes
                If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
                    If CInt(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text) = Cell.Value Then
                        b = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        b = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If
        If Not b Then    
        Set s = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 100, 100) '100s just for the sake of this solution. Not relevant to this question. 
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cell.Value
        'Here I have a bunch of other "s." identifiers for shape customization. Not relevant to this question. 
        missingshapeadded = True
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
missingshapeadded = False
End Sub
```

The boolean variable missingshapeadded is used within my Sheet1>CommandButton. Once my CommandButton is clicked,

```
Call CountShapes     'Counts actual number of shapes
Call AddMissingShape   'Adds missing shape if applicable
If missingshapeadded = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Call AddShape        'Adds shape based on number of shapes present
Call FillTableRow    'Fills table row based on shape number
```

If missingshapeadded = true, my seperate AddShape and FillTable subs are not called. If false, these two are called, thus adding a new shape with the next indexed number.

Comment: So in short, if I understand correctly, you would want to return the first missing number in the sequence? If oval two is missing, you want to return 2, if none is missing you need to know what would be your next number?

Comment: Why do you have an `exit sub` there? Everything will stop as soon as it finds a shape with the cell contents?

Comment: If the number is missing, should the code add an oval with that missing number?

Comment: The reason I have an exit sub is because this sub is called before other subs which count the number of ovals, add ovals, and enter values into the table matrix, respectively. The customweld is a global boolean variable which is later used to determine which value to place into the next Add Oval call. 

If the # oval is missing, I want that # oval to appear.

If the oval isn't missing, I want to add the next oval to appear, fill in the table with that oval #, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of what you're trying to do are not entirely clear to me, but this might help.

I put the numbers 1-4 in A6:A9 and added three ovals named 1, 2 and 4. After running the code it adds an oval containing 3 (called "Oval 3").

It's not clear if you want this sub to add a shape, but if not you could call another sub to that bit?

```
Sub VerifyTable()

Dim WeldNoRange As Range, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim shp As Shape, s As Shape, b As Boolean

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WeldNoRange = ws.Range("A6:A9")

For Each Cell In WeldNoRange
    If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
                If CInt(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text) = Cell.Value Then
                    b = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not b Then
            Set s = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 20, 20, 30)
            s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cell.Value
           s.Name = "Oval " & Cell.Value
        End If
    End If
    b = False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the line: "If Not b Then" mean?

Comment: 'b' is a boolean which returns `False` if the shape is not found on the sheet. If b is false then `not b` is true and that bit of code is executed.

Comment: Doesn't really solve it because my range is bigger than just 4 cells and whenever a cell is vbNullstring, b=false, and then it adds a shape that is empty.

Comment: You just need to move that If clause after the last `Next` line (at the bottom of the `If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then` clause.

Comment: I altered your solution slightly. First, I made the If Cell.Value <> vbNullString a parent off all the code below it. Thus, if a cell is empty, the first for loop doesn't even assign b a value and keeps going through all cells. Secondly, I choose to move the b = false clause into the second for loop. Now If CInt(shp...) = Cell.Value, b = true and the for loop is exited and the first for loop is re-executed.  If CInt(shp...)  <> Cell.Value, b = false, and the If Not b Then section is allowed to execute, resulting in the missing shape being added. I edited my question to show my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like @SJR, I'm not exactly clear on what you try to do but maybe the following can help you find the value of the next oval to be added:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
Dim ArrL As Object: Set ArrL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes 'Change sheet codename accordingly
    If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
        ArrL.Add CLng(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
    End If
Next shp

ArrL.Sort
x = 1
For Each Item In ArrL
    If Item > x Then
        Exit For
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next Item

Debug.Print "First in line is " & x

End Sub
```

If you would implement that into a `Range` object you can tell your macro that, for example, the oval in `WeldNoRange.Cells(x,1)` is missing and should be added.